# how to programatically add attributes to product type

Tags: magento, product

I am working to add attribute affiliate_link (text box) to custom product type. Here is the installer script but unfortunately it's not working :

```
<?php /** @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */


$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'affiliate_link',
    array(
        'type'                    => 'text',
        'backend'                 => '',
        'frontend'                => '',
        'label'                   => 'Affiliate Link',
        'input'                   => 'text',
        'class'                   => '',
        'source'                  => '',
        'global'                  => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'                 => true,
        'required'                => true,
        'user_defined'            => false,
        'default'                 => '',
        'searchable'              => false,
        'filterable'              => false,
        'comparable'              => false,
        'visible_on_front'        => false,
        'unique'                  => false,
        'apply_to'                => 'gift',
        'is_configurable'         => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => false
    )
);


$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId(
    'catalog_product',
    'affiliate_link'
);

 $defaultSetId = $installer->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'default');

$installer->addAttributeGroup(
    'catalog_product',
    $defaultSetId,
    'Affiliate Information'
);

//find out the id of the new group
$groupId = $installer->getAttributeGroup(
    'catalog_product',
    $defaultSetId,
    'Affiliate Information',
    'attribute_group_id'
);

//assign the attribute to the group and set
if ($attributeId > 0) {
    $installer->addAttributeToSet(
        'catalog_product',
        $defaultSetId,
        $groupId,
        $attributeId
    );
}

$installer->endSetup();?>
```

Code for config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cueblocks_Newtype>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Cueblocks_Newtype>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <catalog>
            <product>
                <type>
                    <gift translate="label" module="cueblocks_newtype">
                        <label>Gift Product</label>
                        <model>cueblocks_newtype/product_type</model>
                        <is_qty>0</is_qty>
                        <composite>0</composite>
                        <can_use_qty_decimals>0</can_use_qty_decimals>
                    </gift>
                </type>
            </product>
        </catalog>



         <!-- code omitted for brevity -->
                    <blocks>
            <cueblocks_newtype>
                <class>Cueblocks_Newtype_Block</class>
            </cueblocks_newtype>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <cueblocks_newtype>
                <class>Cueblocks_Newtype_Helper</class>
            </cueblocks_newtype>
        </helpers>
                    <models>
            <cueblocks_newtype>
                <class>Cueblocks_Newtype_Model</class>
            </cueblocks_newtype>
        </models>


        <!-- code omitted for brevity -->
                <resources>
            <cueblocks_newtype_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Cueblocks_Newtype</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                 </cueblocks_newtype_setup>

                    <newtype_write>
    <connection>
    <use>core_write</use>
    </connection>
    </newtype_write>
    <newtype_read>
    <connection>
    <use>core_read</use>
    </connection>
    </newtype_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the code looks fine, but the following piece of code working for me. but its for all product types. and create system attribute. so change

```
  $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'affiliate_link', array(
                 'group'    => 'Affiliate',
                 'label'    => 'Affiliate Link',             
                 'type' => 'varchar',
                 'input'    => 'text',                     
                 'visible'  => true,
                 'required' => true,
                 'position' => 1,
                 'global'   => 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL',
         'note'    => "comments note"
    ));
```

Comment: Hey Asif thanks for looking into this...Lemme give it a try & will get back to you.

Comment: I wonder it's not even adding the new attribute group "Affiliate" which we were trying to add via installer script.It may be some issue with magento 1.9 version....Any Ideas???

Comment: are you sure, installer script is running ?? how you are executing this script ?

Comment: That's the main problem Asif..My installer script is not running...I have placed above mentioned installer code in file app/code/local/cueblocks/newtype/sql/cueblocks_newtype_setup/install-0.1.0.php .But it's not running.   I wonder if I am using the installer file name right with for magento 1.9 edition...

Comment: well, i think installer file name should be mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

Comment: after renaming the file, still it will not execute, because that version of module has already been created, so for testing you can do another trick, write down the installer script in a controller action, and manually execute it from url. here you can create object of installer when writing in controller $installer = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

Comment: Thanks Asif for all your help....I finally figured it out..The problem was with my installer code...I updated it with your code & debuged the cause of not executing the installer script...It's working now..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out..The installer script was not working because I Haven't deleted the entry from  core_resource table...The code posted above by me for installer script  was not working ..I replaced the code by updated code provided by Asif...

But as per the magento default behavior it executes the installer script once at the beginning of module & it adds an entry to the core_resource table by that module name..Now if you will update the same script it will not run because entry corresponding to that is already present in database..To make it run with the updated code I deleted the entry manually from the core_resource table & then tried it with the updated code of Asif...And i works like a Charm!!!

**Notes:-1.)Whenever any magento module executes,it first checks for any installer/update scripts present with the module..So always troubleshoot the scripts by printing an message & die at the very beginning..

2.)If your installer code is not working in the desired manner & you updated the same script..Please check before in core_resource table if entry corresponding to that module is already present..Delete that entry manually & then your updated installer script will work.**